# AWS S3 Storage ObjectLockRetention

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS S3Storage question:  We need to put a retention on objects that can come in everyday.

I see that I can put a retention on the bucket.   I can also put an object lock on the actual object with a retention ( I think).

Our goal is, we want the object to be retained for a year, no matter what bucket they are in.  Right now we are only using one bucket.  I can't really find documentation that explicitly says this can be done. I am finding documentation that deletes all objects in the bucket when the retention date hits. I also see that if an object comes in with a different retentiondate than the bucket, the bucket retention date changes.

So.  one bucket full of objects that have different dates of creation.  How do i retain the objects for exactly one year?  Using C# and would like to use the API.

```
private void AddRetentionToBucket(string bucket)
    {
        var retentionRequest = new PutObjectRetentionRequest()
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Retention = new ObjectLockRetention()
            {
                RetainUntilDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(_retentionYears)
            }
        };

        _client.PutObjectRetentionAsync(retentionRequest);
    }
```

Next step is to do a POC to see if the objects are retained or not retained based on the retention date.
Any comments are welcome.

Thanks

**EDIT**
The idea is.. we will have a lot of objects going into this storage and we want to delete the objects completely after a period of time.  So that we can save space.

Comment: For clarity, by retention do you want the object to be unmodifiable for a certain period and delete it when it reach a certain age? I believe object lock retention doesn't delete the object once it reached the retain until date but it removes the lock and allows the modification on the object. You can add object expiration if you want it to be deleted automatically instead.

Comment: Objects in Amazon S3 do not disappear unless a specific command is issued. Therefore, objects will be "retained" indefinitely. Are you saying that you want to prevent users from being able to _intentionally_ delete an object for a period of time? Or are you saying that you wish to _automatically delete_ objects after a specific period of time? Or both? Please edit your question to clarify these details.